# The DataGrid select all button loading slow

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with ItemsSource and columns with bound values.
For some reason the "select all button" is loading last, so firstly the column headers are aligned to the left and after the whole content is loaded the "select all button" appears. How can I fix that blink?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhesT.png

Here is my code

```
                <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                            Path=Item.RowHeader}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                   MinWidth="55"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <!--m-->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=m, IsAsync=True, StringFormat='{}{0:0.##}'}" Header="m"/>

                    <!--α-->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=a, IsAsync=True}" Header="α" />

                    <!--h-->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=h, IsAsync=True, StringFormat='{}{0:0.#}'}" Header="h" />

                    <!--D1-->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=D1, IsAsync=True, StringFormat='{}{0:F0}'}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock>
                                    D
                                    <InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Subscript">
                                        <TextBlock Text="1"/> 
                                    </InlineUIContainer>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <!--D2-->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=D2, IsAsync=True, StringFormat='{}{0:F0}'}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock>
                                    D
                                    <InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Subscript">
                                        <TextBlock Text="2"/> 
                                    </InlineUIContainer>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>

            </DataGrid>
```